# FIltering jQuery sortable unordered list using selector

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-sortable

I have an asp.net page that has two dynamically built jquery sortable unordered lists.  I am using it to drag and drop items from one list to the other.  That part works fine.  However, I now need to be able to filter the items in on the lists.  I have found code using selectors, but they all seem to utilize list items that include anchors

`('#titles>ul>li>a')`.

When I remove the `'>a"` from the selector, leaving

`'#titles>ul>li'`, it stops working.

I have tried several iterations of things, but nothing seems to work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show other code related to all of this?

Comment: If it's working with the `>a`, then why remove it? I take it your list items don't actually have anchors in them? I second the motion for more code, no one will be able to debug a selector without seeing the markup it is supposed to work against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the [helper code by Kilian Valkhof](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/javascript/how-to-build-a-fast-simple-list-filter-with-jquery/):

```
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a,i,m){
    return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
};
```

This code practically allowed me to use selector :contains in my expressions.

With the helper, I can find any elements that contains the given text. When I have found matching elements, I will look the DOM tree upwards to find the [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) li tag. The matched li tag is what I want to hide (or show).

```
filter = "textToSearch";
$matches = $("ul").find(':contains(' + filter + ')').closest('li');
$('li', list).not($matches).hide();
$matches.show();
```